# If measure of any subset is $0$ or $1$, is the measure Dirac's?

Tags: measure-theory, logic, set-theory

If I have a set $X$ and measure $\mu$ on $\mathcal{P}(X)$ (the power set of $X$) for which holds $\mu(A)\in\{0,1\}$ for every subset $A\subset X$ and $\mu(X)=1$, is this measure necessarily Dirac's? I.e. does there exist some $x\in X$ such that $\mu(A)=[x\in A]$? I think I proved this for when $\text{Card}(X)=\text{Card}(\mathbb{R})$, because then I can pull back this measure $\mu$ to $[0,1]$ along some bijection and then construct $f(t):=\mu^*([0,t])$. Now this $f$ must be a step function. The point where the step happens is our $x$. Now does this hold for any set $X$? My problem is that I can't find a way to define a total ordering on $X$ which has some nice properties that the default ordering on $\mathbb{R}$ has because I find it a little hard identifying these properties... Could I view the set $X$ as the set of ordinals less then some ordinal and then similarly define $f(x):=\mu(\{y\in X|y\le x\})$? Because now $f^{-1}(1)$ must have a minimum and that minimum will be the generator for the Dirac's measure that is equivalent to $\mu$.

Is this proof good?

Comment: See the topic of "measurable cardinal" ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurable_cardinal   Summary: it is consistent with ZFC that there is no measurable cardinal, and your conjecture is correct.  But (as far as we know) it is also consistent with ZFC that measurable cardinals exist, and thus your conjecture is false.

Comment: See also https://mathoverflow.net/q/19414/145247

Comment: @GEdgar This question seems like it's somewhere in between measurable cardinals (where the measure is $\kappa$-additive) and nonprincipal ultrafilters (where the measure is finitely additive), because here I assume we're going with the default assumption of a countably additive measure. Of course, I could be missing something that simplifies that distinction...

Comment: @GEdgar Thank you for that. I see now that my proof is wrong because my function $f$ can be constantly $0$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov I was assuming countable additivity, yes. But it also confused me because it seemed to me that I didn't even need any additivity to derive this (wrong) proof. Now it's more clear to me.

Comment: @MishaLavrov ... Quoting the link: "Ulam showed that the smallest cardinal κ that admits a non-trivial countably-additive two-valued measure must in fact admit a κ-additive measure."

Comment: @GEdgar Yes, that would be what I was missing, thank you!